# Deriving encapsulated classes with different type

Tags: c#, inheritance

## I would like to override a property with a different type.

Let's say I have a Class **Point3D** that inherit from **Point2D**
and a Class **Drawing3D** that inherit from **Drawing2D**.

I'd like both classes Drawing2D, and Drawing3D to have the **same property name Points** which would be a List of Point2D for Drawing2D, and a List of Point3D for Drawing3D.

Having the same property name, I was hoping that Drawing3D would benefit of Drawing2D methods on the property Points.
The thing is I can't use **override** as the types are different. And the keyword **new** doesn't work as Drawing3D seems to have 2 properties Points (a list of Point2D, and a list of Point3D).
Using the base method on a Drawing3D, it will go through the list of Point2D.

My 2D classes:

```
class Point2D
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public Point2D(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public virtual void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"2D Point: [{X}, {Y}]");
    }
}

class Drawing2D
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Point2D> Points { get; set; }

    public Drawing2D(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Points = new List<Point2D>();
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Drawing name: {Name}");
        foreach (var point in Points)
            point.Print();
    }
}
```

My 3D classes based on the 2D classes

```
class Point3D:Point2D
{
    public int Z { get; set; }

    public Point3D(int x, int y, int z):base(x,y)
    {
        Z = z;
    }

    public override void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"3D Point: [{X}, {Y}, {Z}]");
    }
}

class Drawing3D : Drawing2D
{
    public new List<Point3D> Points { get; set; }

    public Drawing3D(string name) : base(name)
    {
        Points = new List<Point3D>();
    }
}
```

And my main program

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Drawing3D myDrawing = new Drawing3D("Sketch");
        myDrawing.Points.Add(new Point3D(1, 2, 3));
        myDrawing.Points.Add(new Point3D(4, 5, 6));
        myDrawing.Print();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The result is that it doesn't print any point. The base method Print() go through the List of Point2D, not Point3D.

Hope you guys can help me.
I like to have elegant code, may be my approach isn't the right one...

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `Point2D` and `Point3D` implement the same interface, let's say `IPoint`. Then in both classes you can make field of type of `IPoint`. Then you can hold there reference to both types of object: `Point2D` and `Point3D`.

This is general rule:

> Porgram to interface, not to an implementation.

which applies here perfectly. This is only one from design principles, which you might want to read about.

In the interface you will implement method `Print()` (which will be implemented appropriately in concrete classes) and method `Print()` from drawing class should delegate the task to `IPoint.Print()`.

Here is your code refactored accordingly to my remarks:

```
public interface IPoint
{
    void Print();
}

class Point2D : IPoint
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public Point2D(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"2D Point: [{X}, {Y}]");
    }
}

class Point3D : IPoint
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Z { get; set; }

    public Point3D(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"3D Point: [{X}, {Y}, {Z}]");
    }
}

class Drawing2D
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<IPoint> Points { get; set; }

    public Drawing2D(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Points = new List<IPoint>();
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Drawing name: {Name}");
        foreach (var point in Points)
            point.Print();
    }
}

class Drawing3D : Drawing2D
{
    public Drawing3D(string name) : base(name) { }
}
```

Comment: I'm doing that only, but just implementing in interface will not solve his concern as `myDrawing.Print();` call will not display points of 3d class. as Print method is inherited from 2d class and it will try to print point of 2d class only.

Comment: @Amit That can be easily solved, see updated answer.

Comment: I afraid that too will not solve his concern. look my answer i have pointed one logical problem in his current flow. However I 100% agree with your suggestion. in fact i too have implement something same

Comment: Thanks Michal for your insight. I'm not familiar with interfaces... still learning. I'm thinking of the solution proposed by dotnetstep below with generics classes. It looks like it solves my issue about the Print method that will work for both Point2D, and Point3D. Shall I have this Generic class implement an interface Print() like you suggest ?

Comment: Well, it's up to you, now I provided code for my approach. Youcan try it and see which is better :)

Comment: Your implementation is good but it allows Point2D added to Drawing3D as well.

Comment: @dotnetstep That is the point of the principle I mentioned, it gives flexibility. This way having one field, you can add 2D and 3D points appropriately with maximum flexibility. But on the other hand, requires more caution from developer (well, in setter method for `Points` you could check for a type and throw exception in case wrong points are added, but that is not the best idea IMO).

Comment: It works too, and looks simple. It shouldn't me a pb for me to mix Point2D/3D  in Drawing2D/3D in my real project. Generic Type looks more intimidating for me as I need to use Constructor (not just default one). May be when I'll be more familiar

Comment: How do you call a constructor of `IPoint` in `Drawing2D`: `Points.Add(new IPoint(2,3))` ? Is it possible ?

Comment: @FlorianHauguel No, interfaces are *abstract* and don't ahve a constructor. Either call constructor of `Point2D` or `Point3D` (or whatever class that implements interface).

Answer (score 2):

If you have to do for above example then you can do something like this.

```
public abstract class Point
    {
       public abstract void Print();
    }

    class Point2D : Point
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }

        public Point2D(int x, int y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }

        public override void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"2D Point: [{X}, {Y}]");
        }
    }

    class Point3D : Point2D
    {
        public int Z { get; set; }

        public Point3D(int x, int y, int z) : base(x, y)
        {
            Z = z;
        }

        public override void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"3D Point: [{X}, {Y}, {Z}]");
        }
    }


    class Drawing<T> where T:Point
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual List<T> Points { get; set; }

        public Drawing(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
            Points = new List<T>();
        }

        public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Drawing name: {Name}");
            foreach (var point in Points)
                point.Print();
        }
    }

    class Drawing3D : Drawing<Point3D>
    {
        public Drawing3D(string name) : base(name)
        {
            Name = name;            
        }
    }

    class Drawing2D : Drawing<Point2D>
    {
        public Drawing2D(string name) : base(name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks nice, and it does work. Shall I do an interface Ipoint in place of abstract Class Point ? Is the solution you mentioned a good practice ?

Answer (score 1):

In your question, you have override method Print of `Point2D` class into `Point3D` class and that is working fine.

Meaning you have dedicated implementation of functionality `Print` in `Point3D` which is seperat from `Point2D`'s `Print` functionality and is supposed to print information about 3D points.

But then you have inherited method `Print` of `Drawing2D` class in `Drawing3D` class, meaning any call to `Print` method from object of `Drawing3D` will execute method of `Drawring2D`.

and now looking into method of `Drawing2D`, you are printing information about Points of `Drawing2D` class (`Drawing2D` has its own List of points and which is different than list of points which `Drwaing3D` have).

so after setting points of `Drwaing3D` when you call `Print` method from `Drawing3D` you are calling `Print` method of `Drawing2D` and that method will try to print information about it's own points (which we haven't set - as we have set points of `Drawing3D`).

So what you can do is,

as you have over-ridden method of `Point` classes, you should also override `Print` method of `Drawing2D` class in `Drwaing3D` class.

like below.

```
class Drawing2D
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<IPoint> Points { get; set; }

    public Drawing2D(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Points = new List<IPoint>();
    }

    public virtual void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Drawing name: {"+Name+"}");
        foreach (var point in Points)
            point.Print();
    }
}

class Drawing3D : Drawing2D
{
    public new List<IPoint> Points { get; set; }

    public Drawing3D(string name) : base(name)
    {
        Points = new List<IPoint>();
    }

    public override void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Drawing name: {"+Name+"}");
        foreach (var point in Points)
            point.Print();
    }
}
```

here `IPoint` is interface which both `Point` class should implement.

```
public interface IPoint
{
    void Print();
}

class Point2D : IPoint
{
public int X { get; set; }
public int Y { get; set; }

public Point2D(int x, int y)
{
    X = x;
    Y = y;
}

public virtual void Print()
{
    Console.WriteLine("2D Point: [{"+X+"}, {"+Y+"}]");
}
}

class Point3D:Point2D, IPoint
{
    public int Z { get; set; }

    public Point3D(int x, int y, int z):base(x,y)
    {
        Z = z;
    }

    public override void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("3D Point: [{"+X+"}, {"+Y+"}, {"+Z+"}]");
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE** (this will be more of inheritance than overriding)

However upper code will work fine. But i don't see it perfect as per flow.

First point: Point is always 1 dimensional so, there should not be 2D Point or 3D point.

Instead, drawing only can be 2D or 3D (here based on number of points it has).

Another thing, in both drawing classes, we have coupled code of printing information. which is repetitive we can put them in one place.

I would propose a code change like below.

single Point class (no multiple implementation or inheritance required here)

```
class Point
{
    public int Val { get; set; }
    public string CordinateName {get; set;}
    public Point(int val, string cordinateName)
    {
        Val = val;
        CordinateName = cordinateName;
    }

    public virtual void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(CordinateName + " Point: [{"+Val+"}]");
    }
}
```

a base drawing class, which hold funtionality of printing and other common properties like Point list and name (which will be common of both 2D or 3D class).

```
class Drawing
{
    public List<Point> Points { get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public Drawing(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Points = new List<Point>();
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Drawing name: {"+Name+"} ");

        foreach (var point in Points)
            point.Print();
    } 
}
```

2D drawing derived from Drawing is pretty much understood.

```
class Drawing2D : Drawing
{
    public Drawing2D(string name, int xPoint, int yPoint) : base (name)
    {
        Points.Add(new Point(xPoint, "X"));
        Points.Add(new Point(yPoint, "Y"));
    }
}
```

3D drawing derived from 2D drawing, as 3D drawing is holding all features of 2D drawing (here X and Y points and inherited features of Drawing class) and also have some other feature (3rd Point) dedicated to 3D drawing only.

```
class Drawing3D : Drawing2D
{
    public Drawing3D(string name, int xPoint, int yPoint, int zPoint) : base(name, xPoint, yPoint)
    {
       Points.Add(new Point(zPoint, "Z"));
    }
}
```

and finally your calling mechanism.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Drawing myDrawing3D = new Drawing3D("Sketch 3D", 10, 12, 14);
        myDrawing3D.Print();

        Drawing myDrawing2D = new Drawing2D("Sketch 2D", 10, 12);
        myDrawing2D.Print();

        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but `Point3D` shouldn't inherit from `Point2D` in my opinion. There's no reason why it should inherit. In general, all pionts: 2D, 3D 4D etc. should only inherit from `IPoint`. But your approach is good and my opinion is just an opinion :) +1

Comment: @MichałTurczyn yes I too was not able to find any relation between 2d and 3d point. but as i was trying to implement same scenario with inheritance rather than overriding (as i think in overriding we are re-writing some code which can be re-use in inheritance) So i kept child - parent relation for now. will update code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Amit for the nice response. I wanted to avoid rewriting all the Print() code in the drawing class. What do you guys think of the answer with Generic Types from dotnetstep below. The drawing.Print() method is written only once

Comment: @Amit There's another principle: Favor composition over inheritance. Although inheritance solves problem of code reuse, it isn't the best approach.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/80045/Composition-VS-Inheritance  it seems like, what to you and what not to use is totally dependant on use case!

Comment: @FlorianHauguel If you have missed it, i have added an updated for your concern of code re usability (and some other changes too).